# Transaction Management in Spring JMS listener

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-jms, distributed-transactions

I have a spring JMS listener which is listening to queue . Once the message arrives at the input queue , it does certain processing on the message and puts the messages to multiple other queues for further processing (we may call these other queues as output queues) . While its posting to other output queues, in case posting the message to one of the output queues may fail due to any reason , I want to make sure that other posts to output queues which are done prior to failure gets rolled back. Basically I want to ensure it as atomic operation . 
is there any annotation/configuration on the listener/container that I can use to achieve this in single transaction.?

Here Is the configuration that I am using

```
<jms:listener-container acknowledge="transacted" cache="session" connection-factory="jmsSecurityFactory" concurrency="1" container-type="default" container-class="abc.xyz">
<jms:listener id="listenerId" destination="inputQueue" ref="" />
</jms:listener-container>
<beans:bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
<beans:property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"></beans:property>
<beans:property name="connectionFactory" ref="inCachingConnectionFactory"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="inCachingConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <beans:property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsSecurityFactory" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="jmsSecurityFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <beans:property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    <beans:property name="username" value=" " />
    <beans:property name="password" value=" " />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <beans:property name="hostName" value="${mq.conn.hostName}" />
    <beans:property name="port" value="${mq.conn.hostPort}" />
    <beans:property name="queueManager" value="${mq.conn.queueManager}" />
    <beans:property name="channel" value="${mq.conn.channel}" />
    <beans:property name="transportType" value="${mq.conn.transportType}" />
    <beans:property name="useConnectionPooling" value="true"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

it looks like JMS template and listener container both refer to same connection factory bean (jmsConnectionFactory)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `acknowledge="transacted"` on the listener container; any downstream operations on the same thread, using a `JmsTemplate` (configured with the same connection factory) will use the container's `Session` and any failure will cause all JMS operations to roll back. The session will be committed by the container on success.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have posted the configuration . It looks like acknowledge attribute is set as intended and also JMS template and container both are using the same connection factory ulitmately. Do you see any issue there?

Comment: "Ulitmately" doesn't cut it; it has to be a reference to the same connection factory for the template to use the container's session.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Removing the CachingConnectionFactory and pointing the JMSTemplate and listener to same conn factory(jmsSecurityFactory in above configration ) worked.

Comment: You may want to consider retaining the `CCF` so the `JmsTemplate` producers can be cached (for efficiency). However, you must set `cacheConsumers` to false, especially when using variable concurrency on the container. You don't want to cache consumers in the CCF, but caching producers provides great benefit.